# stop asp.net btnsave.click event from firing when validation fails

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I have this java script validation function that fires when the client clicks btnsave
if the text of the text box is empty then a message box is displayed and the focus is on the 
text box but i cannot seem to prevent the page from posting back when the validation fails 
AM I missing something. here is my code

```
function validate() 
  {
      var itemscanned;
      itemscanned = document.getElementById('txtItemCode');
      if (itemscanned.value == '') 
      {
          alert("Plz Enter Item Code");
          return false;
         itemscanned.focus
      }
      else 
      {
          alert(itemscanned.value);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Is this the `submit` button for the form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write return before function name like this

```
   <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="buttons"  OnClientClick="return validate()"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

If this is an ASP.NET WebForms application, you really should consider [using the Validator controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). They handle all of client-side logic you are asking for.

If you are using MVC, there is also a way to do [model validation on the client side](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/04/09/adding-client-side-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

add this if its asp.net button control

```
OnClientClick = "return validate();"
```

if it is html button add this

```
onclick = "return validate();"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ît belongs how you handle the events. Please show the asp markup and the binding of the javascript event.

You can try to stop event propagation using javascript:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopPropagation

Note: you have to get the event as an parameter to the validate function:

```
function validate(event) {

    var itemscanned;    
    itemscanned = document.getElementById('txtItemCode');
    if (itemscanned.value == '') {
        alert("Plz Enter Item Code");
        event.stopPropagation();
        itemscanned.focus
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        alert(itemscanned.value);
    }
}​
```

Hope this helps. It's very important how you bind the validate function the button, because asp.net generates a lot of javascript on its own (google for asp.net client validation).